# DataFrame Subset

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe already and am subsetting some of it to another dataframe.

I do that like this:

```
D = njm[['svntygene', 'intgr', 'lowgr', 'higr', 'lumA', 'lumB', 'wndres', 'nlbrst',        'Erneg', 'basallike']]
```

I want to try and set it by the integer position though, something like this:

```
D = njm.iloc[1:, 2:, 3:, 7:]
```

But I get an error. How would I do this part? Read the docs but could not find a clear answer.

Also, is it possible to pass a list to this as values too?

Thanks.

Comment: It's unclear what you want `[1:, 2:, 3:, 7:]` to do.  Do you want to select columns 1, 2, 3, and 7?

Comment: Yes, select all of the data in those columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is covered in the `iloc` section of the [documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#selection-by-position): you can pass a list with the desired indices.

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random((5,5)),columns=list("ABCDE"))
>>> df
          A         B         C         D         E
0  0.605594  0.229728  0.390391  0.754185  0.516801
1  0.384228  0.106261  0.457507  0.833473  0.786098
2  0.364943  0.664588  0.330835  0.846941  0.229110
3  0.025799  0.681206  0.235821  0.418825  0.878566
4  0.811800  0.761962  0.883281  0.932983  0.665609
>>> df.iloc[:,[1,2,4]]
          B         C         E
0  0.229728  0.390391  0.516801
1  0.106261  0.457507  0.786098
2  0.664588  0.330835  0.229110
3  0.681206  0.235821  0.878566
4  0.761962  0.883281  0.665609
```

Comment: In my case when using another dataframe so I just pass the first df where you are using np.random.random etc? Thanks

Comment: @tbonejo: that was just my constructing an example dataframe.  For you, it'd be `njm.iloc[:, [1,2,3,7]]` or something.

Comment: How would I pass in something like: cols=[1,2,3,4,5] to njm.iloc[:,[cols]]? That does not work and thats what I am trying to do.

Comment: @tbonejo: simply `njm.iloc[:, cols]`.  You're passing in a list of one element, containing a list.

Comment: I tried that too but get a TypeError: cannot perform reduce with flexible type.

Comment: I ended up having to make them all int. Like cols = map(int, cols) to make it work.

Comment: @tbonejo: Sorry, I'm confused.  Were you using something other than integers with `iloc`?  All of your examples, and mine too, use integers.